# I Can't view my generated EXCEL DOCS from my computer

Tags: java, android, excel

I can output the files and store then in a location on the device just fine with

```
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Army PRT Manager");

    dir.mkdir();
    File file = new File(dir, fileName);
```

I can view the files on `/storage/emulated/0/Army PRT Manager`

However, when I browse to that folder via my laptop to copy the created documents I can't find the folder.

All folder options have been changed to View `hidden folders/files`.

Is this a problem with many devices and can anyone suggest how I can save in a way that I would be able to see the documents more easily.

Maybe save them to the download folder?

Thanks.

Also when I open my device on my computer it only shows a Internal storage folder to open. I just want to be able to write to a directory that is easy to get to from a computer or file manager on the device. =(

Answer (score 0):

What shows up via the MTP connection to your laptop is what `MediaStore` knows about. Use [`MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html) to tell `MediaStore` about your file, after you have completely written it to disk.

Even with this, depending upon your laptop's OS, you may need to do some sort of "refresh" in a file manager to get it to pick up the new file, or possibly even unplug and re-plug in the device.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after `dir.mkdir()`

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{dir.toString()}, null, null);
```